# Ajax if not working. How to it work?

Tags: ajax, if-statement

The if in this block making the website to hang. If I remove the "if" it works perfectly. But I need to add the variable check for lock. How can I do it?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl(' //customer/financial/paymentplan',array('name'=>'Contract[paymentplanservicefee]','countryid'=>'')); ?>' + $('#Customer_countryid').val(),
    success: function (data) {
        if ($locked) $('#paymentplanselect').html(data);
    },
});
```

In this file I also have this thing for the view.

```
<td>
                        <div id='paymentplanselect'><?php
                            $listdata = Financial::getPaymentPlans($model->countryid);
                            echo $form->dropDownList($contract, 'paymentplanservicefee', $listdata, array('empty'=>' - select payment plan - ', 'disabled'=>$locked)); 
                        ?></div>
                        <?php echo $form->error($contract,'paymentplanservicefee'); ?>
                    </td>
```

Comment: you haven't provided enough code. what's `$locked` do? that's your problem.

Comment: I don't see the closing `?>` php block, also, it seems that you forgot to include some part of your code that would help us to understand the problem.

Comment: The $locked is a variable to check the authorization. If not authorized I don't want to load the data.

Comment: @Bee Have you thoroughly verified whether or not `locked` is on the state that it should be?

Comment: @cacigenate yes
<?php    if(!$locked && !Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('fullClientContract')) { $temp=$locked; $locked = true; }?>

Comment: @PedroLobito <?php echo $this->createUrl(' //customer/financial/paymentplan',array('name'=>'Contract[paymentplanservicefee]','countryid'=>'')); ?> the ending is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there will be no $locked here.It should be only locked a var type varriable. Which should be like this before the ajax block:

```
    var locked = "<?php echo $locked ?>";
```